# Как записать видео с рабочего стола на Windows?

Tags: python, python-2.x

Как записать видео с рабочего стола в Windows? Без бинарников (типа `ffmpeg.exe`) и записью видео в файл.

Comment: Что значит на windows? Расскажите конкретнее что вы хотите ибо задача не ясна

Comment: В системе windows

Comment: связанный вопрос [Capture video data from screen in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35097837/4279)

Comment: opencv, gstreamer

Comment: Можно пример кода?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTlgVCrO7IQ

Comment: А как там настроить чтобы экран полностью записывался?(Параметр какой)